# Combinar entre mouseover y click en jquery

Tags: jquery

Soy un poco novato en jquery, a ver si me podeis ayudar. Estoy haciendo una página para mostrar mapas de pronóstico del tiempo según la hora del pronóstico. Quiero combinar mouseover y click para visualizar dichos mapas. Tengo 2 botones. Quiero que al pulsar un botón se vean los mapas pasando el ratón por encima de la hora (con mouseover), y  al pulsar otro botón se visualicen sólo haciendo click en la hora (con click).
Por ahora me funciona sólo la primera vez, al pulsar en el botón de "Sin click" ya siempre visualizo los mapas con mouseover, aún pulsando de nuevo el botón "Con click".

Los botones del html son

```
input type="button" name="boton" id="boton" value="Con click"      
input type="button" name="boton2" id="boton2" value="Sin click"

y el código de jquery es 

$("#boton2").on("click",function(){
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').mouseover(function() {
    ........aqui va el codigo para pasar los mapas....
});
});

$("#boton").on("click",function(){
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').click(function() {
    ...........aqui va el mismo código que arriba.....
});
});
```

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Igual que utilizas `on` para asociar una función a un evento puedes utilizar `off` para desasociarla:

```js
function mostrar(){
  // Código a ejecutar en el evento
  // ....
  console.log('Mostrar pronóstico');
}

$("#boton2").click(function(){
   // Eliminar controlador de click
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').off('click', mostrar);
   // Añade controlador a mouseover
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').on('mouseover', mostrar);
});

$("#boton").click(function(){
   // Elimina controlador de mouseover
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').off('mouseover', mostrar);
   // Añade controlador a click
   $('.class_seleccion_pronostico').on('click', mostrar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton">Botón con click</button>
<button id="boton2">Botón con mouseover</button>

<div class="class_seleccion_pronostico">Hora</div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Funciona. Pero cómo se haría para que por defecto funcione con mouseover? Hasta ahora cuando entro en la página no me muestra ningún mapa hasta que presiono alguno de los 2 botones. Me gustaría que por defecto funcionara con mouseover sin presionar ningún botón.

Comment: No tienes más que ejecutar la instrucción `$('.class_seleccion_pronostico').on('mouseover', mostrar);`

Comment: OK. Muchas gracias! Funcionan los dos botones y eligo o click o mouseover con ellos, y por defecto entro con mouseover. Pero queda un pequeño detalle. Quiero que al entrar en la página se muestre el primer mapa de pronóstico. Por ahora solo muestra el mapa hasta que situo el ratón encima del número de la hora del pronóstico.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Simplemente tendrías que llamar a la función `mostrar` ¿no? `mostrar();`

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación no se debe usar el **on** en funciones que se ejecutan varias veces como el ejemplo de mas arriba puesto que sino tienes un control de las funciones  estas se irán "encolando" al elemento  y cada vez que se realice la función determinada se realizara **N** veces se haya asignado.

```js
     
$('#btnShow').attr("onmouseover","mostrar();");

function mostrar(){
  // Código a ejecutar en el evento
  console.log('Mostrar pronóstico');
}

function mostrarClick(){
  // Setea el atributo onclick con la funcion y mouseover se limpia
  $('#btnShow').attr("onclick","mostrar();");
  $('#btnShow').attr("onmouseover","");
}

function mostrarMouseover(){
 // Setea el atributo mouseover con la funcion y onclick se limpia
  $('#btnShow').attr("onmouseover","mostrar();");
  $('#btnShow').attr("onclick","");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton" onclick="mostrarClick();">Botón con click</button>
<button id="boton2" onclick="mostrarMouseover();">Botón con mouseover</button>

<div id="btnShow" class="class_seleccion_pronostico" onclick="" onmouseover="" >Hora</div>
```